# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras' for Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, keras, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I was running Jupyter Notebook and the following error occurs

> ModuleNotFoundError
>   Traceback (most recent call last)
>    
>   in 
>   ---->
>
> from keras.models import Sequential
>
> from keras.layers import (
>      Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten,     Dense, Dropout)
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'

I have tried using 
`import sys; sys.path` and found this

```
['/home/xxx/notebook',
 '/home/xxx/anaconda3/lib/python37.zip',
 '/home/xxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.7',
 '/home/xxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '',
 '/home/xxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/home/xxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/home/xxx/.ipython']
```

Is there any problem with the installation? Do I need to reinstall everything from python to anaconda. Would some be able to point me to a proper installation of anaconda

BTW, if u have installed python, should you install python package through anaconda again

Thanks

Comment: Did you actually install keras and tensorflow in anaconda?

Comment: It is possible that you have more than one version of python on your machine, and Keras has been installed on a version different from the version running the Jupyter. Did you install keras and jupyter both via anaconda?

Comment: @Matias Valdenegro: I am sorry but I vaguely have the believe that they are packaged together with anaconda. Does keras and tensorflow comes packaged with anaconda?

Comment: You need to install them

Comment: @ alift   before installing anaconda, I have installed python v2. afterwhich i have installed anaconda

Comment: @Matias Valdenegro : Sorry novice to keras, and jupyter notebook

Answer (score 14):

You have to install all the dependencies first before using it.
Try using

- conda install tensorflow
- conda install keras

by installing it with conda command it manage your versions compatibility with other libraries.

with pip install libraries will only install in your current environment and the latest version of the library sometimes latest libraries are not compatible with the other libraries so we have to take care of version compatibility.

Answer (score 11):

keras is actually part of tensorflow so all you have to do is just

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,Dropout,Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
```

cheers mate

Comment: eh... but it dun seem to work....  it gives an error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow' "

Comment: perhaps u had forgotten to import tensorflow or u have not install it into your environment

Comment: Whats weird is I still have to use "from tensorflow.keras.models import xyz" even after using the line "from tensorflow import keras".

Answer (score 2):

Create a virtual environment and install all packages and specially jupyter-notebook in it. **Some times it is necessary to install jupyter-notebook in each virtual environment to work properly with other libraries.**
It is preferred to use **anaconda**.

**After creating your virtual env** use this command to install jupyter:

```
conda install -c anaconda jupyter
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed all the required packages in a virtual/conda environment, have you tried saving the environment as an ipython kernel? I got those errors when I tried to launch a jupyter notebook from my virtual environment but I hadn't explicitly created a kernel for it.

https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html

Answer (score 0):

Install packages in Anaconda Navigator -> Enviroments -> Play button -> Open Terminal -> conda install keras

Answer (score 0):

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,Dropout,Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
```

These two import statements worked for me.