# Module Keras displayed as "no module name 'keras'" while installed in virtual environment

Tags: python, keras, virtualenv, jupyter

I know there is plenty topics about this particular issue but none of them solved it. 
I use a virtual environment called `deeplearning` in a Jupyterlab notebook.

## the error itself

I have troubles to import `keras` or `tensorflow` while trying to import a model object [even with "solution" proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56641218/10314460)

```
from keras.models import Sequential
#or
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
```

Then it returns the following errors:

```
----> 1 from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

## modules installed

In my `deeplearning` virtual environment the following modules are installed:

```
(base) user@machine:~$ conda activate deeplearning
(deeplearning) user@machine:~$ conda list
# packages in environment at /home/user/anaconda3/envs/deeplearning:
+------------+---------+--------------------+
|    Name    | Version |       Build        |
+------------+---------+--------------------+
| python     |   3.6.7 | h0371630_0         |
| jupyterlab |  0.35.3 | py36_0             |
| jupyter    |   1.0.0 | py36_7             |
| tensorflow |   2.0.0 | mk1_py36hef7ec59_0 |
| keras      |   2.3.1 | 0                  |
+------------+---------+--------------------+
```

At first sight I thought the `Build` indicated as `0` was a problem but while `tensorflow` cannot be imported too... I do not know.

## activation of environment and usage in notebook

I activated the `deeplearning` environment in a terminal, added it in the list of kernels using the following command `ipython kernel install --user --name=deeplearning`, then chose the kernel `deeplearning` available in the notebook.

I don't know if this all normal but when I check in the list of the path I do not see the path of my virtual environment in it:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
['/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python37.zip',
 '/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7', 
'/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', 
'', 
'/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages', 
'/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions', 
'/home/user/.ipython']
```

I wonder if this is the core of the problem and I have no idea what to do with all the attempts I already tried.

## UPDATE about new attempts

I did launch the jupyterlab notebook in the virtual environment:

```
(base) user@machine:~$ conda activate deeplearning 
(deeplearning) user@machine:~$ jupyter lab --no-browser.
```

*for the ones who has troubles with the error `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'io_loop'` the solution proposed by [eroz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51749538/10314460) did work for me*

**But** `keras` and `tensorflow` are still the troubling modules. While using the commands `!which python` it clearly indicates `/home/user/anaconda3/envs/deeplearning/bin/python` and `!conda list` displays the right set of modules, in the right kernel, with `keras` and `tensorflow` in it. Instead, other modules like `pickle` or `sklearn` work well.

## UPDATE about what works.

In the terminal itself this is alright:

```
(deeplearning) user@machine:~$ python
Python 3.6.7 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 23 2018, 19:16:44) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
>>> 
#so no issue of module name
```

It seems the main problem is about the Anaconda/JupyterLab environment. But no idea how to solve it.

Comment: In the notebook, can you try the following: `!which python`, and `!conda list`?

Comment: Another possibility: On the terminal, try: `which ipython`.

Comment: @KotaMori Yes, in the notebook with `deeplearning` kernel selected, the command `!which python` indicates `/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python`. Still in this notebook `!conda list` does return my base environment with modules built on python 3.7 and not 3.6 like in the `deeplearning` conda's virtual environment. This seems clear that even if I choose the `deeplearning` kernel it does not use the modules inside it. But why ? I don't know.

Comment: besides there is no `keras` or `tensorflow` modules in the base environment, this is not compatible with 3.7 for the moment.

Comment: An easy fix would be to launch jupyter from the deeplearning env, though. Then Python3 kernel would be the deeplearning env. Do you prefer to add the env as a kernel?

Comment: @KotaMori Because I am novice in virtual environments usage, I will tell the steps I did, in order to be sure we are on the same "wavelength". Step1 I activated the `deeplearning` environment in a terminal as `(base) user@machine:~$ conda activate deeplearning`. Step2 I launched jupyterlab in it as `(deeplearning) user@machine:~$ jupyter lab --no-browser`. Step3 I copied and paste the link in my browser as usal but the terminal started to display some conflicts: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'io_loop'`, printing it in a infinite times. The way I tried seems fatal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214433/discussion-between-kota-mori-and-avywam).